# Jasmine CI and Capturing Test Result Output on Jenkins Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, jasmine, jasmine-headless-webkit

**Background**:

Have inherited a Ruby on Rails 3.1.x project which is in need of some BDD and testing for Javascript code.  So following the [Instructions](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem) I have added the **jasmine** gem for JS testing. This works ok via **rake jasmine** and gives me the local web-server accessible via http://some-host.com:8888/

**Problem**:

What I want to do is use the tests on the CI server, which is running Jenkins.  The Jenkins project is setup with the command `rake jasmine:ci` to run the CI variant of Jasmine.  The output on the Jenkins build console log is below:

```
Waiting for jasmine server on 32901...
jasmine server started.
Waiting for suite to finish in browser ...
................

Finished in 0.00454 seconds
16 examples, 0 failures
 * Stopping Xvfb :66.0 Xvfb
   ...done.
```

I'd like to capture the output; as in the view that is generated from the Jasmine web server page and preserve this with the build run.  I've tried the obvious of seeing if there is an `-o <filename.out>` option, but not had any success.

Does anyone know how to capture the output in the context of running in a CI instance ?  Does it require **PhantomJS** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use phantomjs in combination with a junit compatible xml reporter for jasmine. Then I simply use the JUnit Jenkins plugin.

The junit reporter and glue code can be found here:

https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

This github project by Larry Myers has a good example setup for this. It contains a rhino and a phantomjs setup. I have only tried the phantomjs part and I am really pleased.